# sum of the series and infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we have a series of numbers $$1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + \cdots + (10^n)^5.$$ Final sum of the series is approximately equal $16666\ldots$ .

If  there is more and more numbers in the series is the result of closer and closer to $16666\ldots$ .

For example if the last number $1000$ or $10000$ or $100000$ and so on, the final sum is closer to $16666\ldots$ . then $n\to \mathbb{\infty}$ $$1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + \cdots(10^n)^5 = \frac 1 6 * (10^n)^6$$
Now same story, If we have a series of numbers $$1^{59} + 2^{59} + 3^{59} + \cdots + (10^n)^{59}.$$ Final sum of the series is approximately equal $16666\ldots$ .

If there is more and more numbers in the series is the result of closer and closer to $16666\ldots$ .

For example if the last number $1000$ or $10000$ or $100000$ and so on, the final sum is closer to $16666\ldots$ .  if $n\to \mathbb{\infty}$  then $$1^{59} + 2^{59} + 3^{59} + \cdots(10^n)^{59} = \frac 1 {60} * (10^n)^ {60}$$ 
Whether we can concludeif $n\to \mathbb{\infty}$ $$1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + \cdots + (10^n)^5 = 1^{59} + 2^{59} + 3^{59} + \cdots + (10^n)^{59}$$ srbija

Comment: Hello. What exactly is your question? Feel free to edit your post and include it.

Comment: What is this $16666\dots$? This is not a number. In my opinion all of this is just nonsense.

Comment: Using the identity $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ki^5=\frac16k^6+$some terms in $k^5$ for $k=10^n$ shows that the result is $\frac1610^{6n}+$some rest of order $10^{5n}$, thus the leading part $166666\cdots$ of the base-$10$ expansion with $n$ or $n-1$ successive $6$s. Likewise with the exponent $59$ since $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ki^{59}=\frac1{60}k^{60}+$some terms in $k^{59}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which do you think is closer to 16666: 16666666666, or 20000?

As $n$ tends to infinity, the sum
$f(n) = 1^{59} + 2^{59} + 3^{59} + \cdots + (10^n)^{59}$ will grow
much, much faster than $g(n) = 1^{5} + 2^{5} + 3^{5} + \cdots + (10^n)^{5}$.
As noted in a comment, for large enough $n$,
$f(n)$ is approximately $\frac{1}{60} 10^{60n}$ whereas
$g(n)$ is approximately $\frac16 10^{6n}$.
That is,
$$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \approx \frac{\frac{1}{60} 10^{60n}}{\frac16 10^{6n}}
   = 10^{54n - 1}.$$
That's a very big difference in my opinion. Another way of looking at it is,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1^{5} + 2^{5} + 3^{5} + \cdots + (10^n)^{5}}
{1^{59} + 2^{59} + 3^{59} + \cdots + (10^n)^{59}} = 0.$$

So I would not say these are at all equal, except in the limited sense
that both grow without bound as $n$ tends to infinity.
But in that sense—that is, if you care only that both quantities
go toward the same "value", regardless of how quickly they go 
toward it—you might as well say that as $n\to\infty$,
$$1^{5} + 2^{5} + 3^{5} + \cdots + (10^n)^{5} 
\;\mathop{\unicode{x201C}\!=\!\unicode{x201D}}\; \sqrt n,$$
because 
$\lim_{n\to\infty} 1^{5} + 2^{5} + 3^{5} + \cdots + (10^n)^{5} = \infty$
and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt n = \infty$.
(Notice the quotation marks around one of the equality (=) signs above,
indicating a place where I would not normally set an equality sign.)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is yes. However, both sums are all equal to $+\infty$ which is not actually a real number!